Configuring I/O Module: NPN/PNP Switching via Microcontroller (24V)

I’m currently working on an embedded solution to replicate the functionality of an I/O module, similar to the B&R X20 series. Specifically, I want to configure the outputs so that I can switch between NPN and PNP modes, depending on the need. The switching should be controlled by a microcontroller.
The system is operating with 24V signals, and I’ve already developed a circuit that logically performs the switching between NPN and PNP. However, the current version is only designed for lower voltages, and I’m unsure how to adapt this circuit to handle 24V without using galvanic isolation (e.g., optocouplers). 1
The Circuit 1 is from another post: How can I control PNP and NPN transistors together from one pin?
My question is: How can I design a circuit that allows switching between NPN and PNP outputs for 24V signals via a microcontroller? Are there any typical pitfalls I should be aware of? Or am I possibly overlooking something important?

Do they need to be 2 physical BJT or are you just after a change of polarity active/high low? Because the latter is super trivial to do in software.

I would like to have an NPN / PNP output (24V/0.1A) configured by microcontroller. Now I have read that this is often done with PushPull configurations, so I need 2 BJT.

If the PNP transistor in your design is powered with +24V at its emitter, and the input control signal is only 0V or +5V, then that transistor will be permanently on. To switch it off would require +24V at its base, which cannot happen if the control signal never exceeds +5V.
Here's a solution to that:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When IN is high (+5V) "NPN LOAD" is activated, having the full 24V across it, and "PNP LOAD" is off. When IN is low (0V) "PNP LOAD" is powered on with the full 24V, while "NPN LOAD" is off.
An additional transistor Q2 is necessary to invert and translate the 0V/5V digital input into 24V/0V levels for the PNP Q3. By contrast, the NPN Q1 will work just fine with the original 0V/5V signal.

Thanks for the answer, that helps me! In the meantime, I have looked into a possible PushPull solution. I would share this. This is my first post in the forum. Should I reply to my question or edit the original post?

@Backed4360 I would update the question. As I understood it, you wanted to operate two distinct loads, one with a PNP and one with an NPN. If a push-pull arrangement would satisfy your requirements, then the question is ambiguous, and you should clear that up.
